# Reference for R VGLM function

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, references

Could someone please either explain to me what the VGLM function in R does or point me towards comprehensive documention? Currently, the only documentation I can find does not explain what a Vector GLM is, such as seen [here](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/VGAM/html/vglm.html). A worked through example would be fine.

Comment: How about the references mentioned in the documentation page you link to?  The Yee/Wild paper seems like it explains it fully and has a non-proportional odds model example.  The Yee/Hastie paper specifically references this library and has several examples, and there is code for at least one in the appendix. Plus the documentation page you link to also has several examples.  What more are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the references in the documentation of the `VGAM` R package, there is now even a book "Vector Generalized Linear and Additive Models: With an Implementation in R (Springer Series in Statistics)" by the same authos as the R package.  See [https://www.amazon.com/Vector-Generalized-Linear-Additive-Models/dp/1493941984/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1534868939&sr=8-1&keywords=vector+generalized+linear+models&dpID=41INcDCkR9L&preST=_SY291_BO1,204,203,200_QL40_&dpSrc=srch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1493941984)

Comment: I have got the book but I could not find a way to use cluster-robust standard errors with vglm yet.
If you are familiar with vglm, I would appreciate you having a look at this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/521181/cluster-robust-standard-errors-after-vglm