# Cluster-robust standard errors after vglm

Tags: standard-error, ordinal-data, generalized-additive-model, ordered-logit, clustered-standard-errors

I have estimated an ordered logistic regression with the vglm function of the VGAM package in R.

Here is a minimalistic example of what I did:

```
library(VGAM)

cdata <- data.frame(y = ordered(as.factor(rep(1:3, 1000))), 
                   x1 = rnorm(3000,50,1), 
                   x2 = rbinom(3000, 1, 0.4), 
                group = sort(rep(1:100,10)))

orderedlogit <- vglm(y ~ x1 + x2, cumulative(parallel = FALSE), cdata)
```

Now I would like to estimate cluster robust standard errors for the groups defined by the group variable.

I have tried the package lmtest in combination with sandwich since it is compatible with polr [as described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209496/r-clustering-standard-errors-in-masspolr), but for vglm it gives the following error:

> Error in UseMethod("estfun") :
> no applicable method for 'estfun' applied to an object of class "c('vglm', 'vlm', 'vlmsmall')"

Does anyone know how to get cluster robust standard errors for a vglm object?

Comment: I don't think vglm has an option for that. But, GEE type estimation for multinomial outcomes are implemented in the R package multgee.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look at that package as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I switched to Stata and used the user-written [gologit2 package](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4794699_GOLOGIT2_Stata_module_to_estimate_generalized_logistic_regression_models_for_ordinal_dependent_variables).